# detect the user have scrolled to the lowest portion of page - jQuery

Tags: jquery

in http://api.jquery.com/one/ or in facebook they detect when you are at the bottom of the page and fetch more data [whatever they want] to show !

how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your need is to detect the user is at the lowest portion, the following code will work

```
<div class="test">not at bottom</div>
<div class="test">not at bottom</div>
<div class="test">not at bottom</div>
....
<div class="test">not at bottom</div>
<div class="test">not at bottom</div>

<div id="placeholder">placeholder</div>


$(window).scroll(function check(){
  var top = $("#placeholder").offset().top;
  if($(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > top){
      $(".test").each(function(){$(this).html("at bottom")});
  }else{
      $(".test").each(function(){$(this).html("not at bottom")});
  }
});
```

You can see this at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMH5H/3/) .

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called Lazy Loading.

This can be probably easily accomplished using the [Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)

Source is available on [github](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery creator John Resig has a post on his blog about the right and wrong way to do this - http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/